# Serial.println cuts off first digit

Tags: serial, analogread, print

I'm trying to perform a simple analogRead() and print out the result, as below:

```cpp
void getVoltMeter() {

  readValue = analogRead(A2);
  readByte = readValue/4; 
  Serial.println(readValue);
  Serial.println(readByte);

}
```

But the output is:

```cpp
023
255
```

The voltage input is 5V, so I would expect it to read:

```cpp
1023
255
```

Why is the first digit being cut off?

Comment: What board are you using?

Comment: What does it look like if you swap order of the println() commands?

Comment: What happens if you add a `Serial.println()` first?

Comment: josecanuc: if I swap the print commands, it reads "4, 1024"
@Majenko I'm using an Uno. If I put a blank print statement first, it prints the values as expected without truncation, so this is a solution. I mostly just want to understand what's going on that would make this happen.

Comment: What are you viewing the output in?

Comment: In the serial monitor

Comment: You must share your full sketch here.